# SAPUI5 Smartform Fields Not Editable

Tags: sapui5

I have managed to setup a [Smartform](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm/) for update / delete purposes. Binding works alright, fields are visible but all of them are read only. Of course, form `editable` attribute is set to `true`.

OData model looks good:

- `creatable`, `updatable`, and `deletable` flags are checked for the entity set
- All fields have the `creatable` flag
- All fields, except the keys, have the `updatable` flag in entity type.

Backend methods are in place and tested in the gateway client. Followed the steps required to clear the server cache (without being sure it's required) but situation remains the same.

Is there something that I'm missing or a place that I forgot to have a look here?

Answer (score 0):

​Solution found and had nothing to do with my coding. It was all about closing SAP Personal Web IDE, stopping and restarting the Orion service, logging in again and just rerunning the application. Form behaves now as supposed without alerting a single line of code...